# Why isn't my div scroll working?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, scroll

I want the page to scroll to the `scrolling` class name in my `index.js` file whenever the user clicks on it.  Right now, my screen is blank with nothing on it after I hit `cmd + s` and then `cmd + r`.

Here's my `index.html` file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
     <title>My practice web app</title>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
     <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@15/dist/react.js"></script>
     <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@15/dist/react-dom.js"></script>
     <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.6.16/browser.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="firstBar"></div>

    <script type="text/babel" src="index.js"></script>

  </body>

</html>
```

Here's my `index.js` file:

```
var Website = React.createClass({
  scrolling: function() {
    $("button").click(function() {
    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(".scrollTo").offset().top},
        'slow');
});
  },

  render: function() {
    return(

      <div className="container">
      <kbd className="fullName">My practice web app</kbd>
        <button onClick={this.scrolling} type="button" className="btn btn-primary portfolio">Portfolio</button>
        <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary about">About</button>
        <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary contact">Contact</button>
        <div className="scrollTo">
        <img src={"./pictures/myPic3.JPG"} className="myPic"></img>
        <p>Portfolio</p>
        </div>
      </div>

    );
  }


});

ReactDOM.render(<Website/>, document.getElementById('firstBar'));
```

Here are the errors I'm getting:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: http://192.168.1.8:8080/index.js: Unexpected token (10:2)
at Parser.pp.raise (browser.js:2027)
at Parser.pp.unexpected (browser.js:2596)
at Parser.pp.expect (browser.js:2590)
at Parser.pp.parseObj (browser.js:1447)
at Parser.pp.parseExprAtom (browser.js:1250)
at Parser.parseExprAtom (browser.js:26392)
at Parser.pp.parseExprSubscripts (browser.js:1097)
at Parser.pp.parseMaybeUnary (browser.js:1079)
at Parser.pp.parseExprOps (browser.js:1035)
at Parser.pp.parseMaybeConditional (browser.js:1018)
```

Comment: You're missing a `,` in your object literal

Comment: @AluanHaddad I fixed that, it doesn't work. Page's still completely blank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed by @AluanHaddad, you have a **syntax error**: the object passed to [React.createClass](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-api.html#createclass) must contain comma separated values (to be a valid JavaScript Object):

```
React.createClass({
  key1: function() { /* ... */ },
  key2: function() { /* ... */ },
  key1: function() { /* ... */ },
});
```

But, despite that, you're binding button click with react, and, then, when user click it, you're binding **another event** with jQuery.

Just let React handle the event:

```
var Website = React.createClass({

  scrolling: function() {
    $('html,body').animate(
      {
        scrollTop: $(".scrollTo").offset().top
      },
      'slow'
    );
  },

  render: function() {
    return(

      <div className="container">
        <kbd className="fullName">My practice web app</kbd>
        <button onClick={this.scrolling} type="button" className="btn btn-primary portfolio">Portfolio</button>
        <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary about">About</button>
        <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary contact">Contact</button>
        <div className="scrollTo">
          <img src={"./pictures/myPic3.JPG"} className="myPic"></img>
          <p>Portfolio</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      );
  }


});

ReactDOM.render(<Website/>, document.getElementById('firstBar'));
```

Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mrlew/axvyf97L/ (just click portfolio button).

Some suggestions:

1) you're loading babel at the browser: it's just for testing purposes (don't know if it's your case; if so, please ignore). Please, consider pre-transpile your js file first with a bundler like [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/). From the [docs](https://babeljs.io/docs/setup/#installation):

> Compiling in the browser has a fairly limited use case, so if you are
>   working on a production site you should be precompiling your scripts
>   server-side. See setup build systems for more information.

2) you're mixing jQuery with React: all DOM manipulation and event binding should be done with React.

Comment: @mrlew why would that result in a parse error from Babel?

Comment: @chompy you're welcome. I edited with some suggestions, If you allow me.

Comment: @AluanHaddad After your message, I tryed this code in [babel online transpiler](https://babeljs.io/repl/) and transpiled successfully.

Comment: I'm not saying it doesn't work I'm just wondering what caused the original error.

Comment: @AluanHaddad Sure, I understood now, you're right, didn't focused on the pre-edit issue. I edited my answer with your note and with the explanation. Thanks

Comment: Actually I prefer transpiling in the browser with SystemJS during development. There's nothing wrong with doing that at all just bundle for production. I do agree with the script being in a separate file though

Comment: Sure, it's your choice. Nothing "wrong". Just know that *Compiling in the browser has a fairly limited use case*, as the vendor says.